# Fluent UI DatePicker formatDate date

Tags: datepicker, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I am working on a project with [Fluent UI](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web) and `React JSX` and my question is how to *format date* of [DatePicker](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/datepicker) component to be `day.month.year` format?

**Example:**

```js
<DatePicker
  ...
  formatDate={(date) => {
    return (date.getMonth() + "." + date.getDate() + "." + date.getFullYear)
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Hi @Ștefania and welcome to SO. When you ask a question put your code as text not as picture, or provide Codepen/JSFiddle working example.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to format date of `DatePicker Component` use `formatDate` method:

```js
const formatDate = (date?: Date): string => {
  if (!date) return '';
  const month = date.getMonth() + 1; // + 1 because 0 indicates the first Month of the Year.
  const day = date.getDate();
  const year = date.getFullYear();

  return `${day}.${month}.${year}`;
}

<DatePicker
  ...
  formatDate={formatDate}
/>
```

[Codepen working example](https://codepen.io/savkelita/pen/KKXVmYm?editors=0011).

Useful links:

[DatePicker documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui/#/controls/web/datepicker)

[MDN Date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, and shows the formatted date depending on the locale:

```
formatDate={(date?: Date) => date.toLocaleDateString()}
```